# How should we handle the questions: "What did X mean when he said ..." on SF&F?

Tags: discussion

There have been numerous questions popping up asking for an explanation as to what a character meant when he/she said this to someone. Some of them are here (that I know of) asked in the past few days:

- [Why did Rocket say, "Not it"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224540/why-did-rocket-say-not-it)
- [What did Harry mean when he said "Well, I take it you're not sorry?" to Griphook?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224502/what-did-harry-mean-when-he-said-well-i-take-it-youre-not-sorry-to-griphook)
- [Why did Dr. Chiren ask Dr. Ido that question?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224488/why-did-dr-chiren-ask-dr-ido-that-question)
- [What is meant by "Anything that challenges Zalem"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224391/what-is-meant-by-anything-that-challenges-zalem)
- [Why did Black Widow say, "Please"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223838/why-did-black-widow-say-please)

and a lot more...

In my opinion, this could go on forever if one starts listing each phrase from every book/movie.

So, how can we handle such questions?

Comment: [Also related](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12551/58193).